# Pattern for rest query params in flask

Tags: mysql, sql, rest, flask, flask-restful

Is there a pattern for dealing with query params in a flask rest server? I know I can create a sql query word for word using string manipulation in python, but I find that to be ugly and error prone, I was wondering if there is a better way. Here's what I have:

```
param1 = request.args.get('param1', type = int)
param2 = request.args.get('param2', type = int)

if param1 is not None:
    if param2 is not None:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE p1 = %s AND p2 = %s", (str(param1), str(param2)))
    else:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE p1 = %s", (str(param1),))
else:
    if param2 is not None:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE p2 = %s", (str(param2),))
    else:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
```

It's easy to see the number of possible SQL statements is 2 to the number of parameters, which grows out of control... so, again, without using string manipulation to custom build the sql query, is there an idiom or pattern that is used to accomplish this in a more elegant way? Thanks.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through your parameters.

```
params = []
for i in range(1, HoweverManyParamsYouNeed):
    params.append(request.args.get('param' + str(i), type = int))

s = ""
for i in range(1, len(params)):
    if params[ i ] is not None:
        if not s:
            s = "p" + str(i) + " = " + str(params[ i ])
        else:
            s = s + " AND p"  + str(i) + " = " + str(params[ i ])

full = "SELECT * FROM table"
if s:
    full = full + " WHERE " + s
cursor.execute(full)
```

You might need to correct this code, since I do not have a way to run it.

Comment: 'any number of arguments' means you'll have to create at least part of your query dynamically. No, there is no better way.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using ORM(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) instead of raw sql queries.

- First you need install flask-sqlalchemy (https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/)
- Then define your model

```
    class MyModel(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        column1 = db.Column(db.Integer)
        column2 = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

- Let's say you have your filter lookup somewhere

```
    allowed_filters = {"column1", "column2"}
```

- Finally instead of cursor you can use SQLAlchemy's ORM to retrieve your filtered objects.

```
    query = MyModel.query
    for field, value in request.args.items():
        if field in allowed_filters:
            query = query.filter(getattr(MyModel, field) == value)
    my_object_list = list(query.all())
```

If you really want to create your queries manually you can always iterate over args:

```
    where_clause = ""
    params = []
    for field, value in request.args.items():
        if field in allowed_filters:
            if len(where_clause) > 0:
                where_clause += " AND "
            where_clause += "{} = %s".format(field)
            params.append(value)
    if len(where_clause) > 0:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE {}".format(where_clause), tuple(params))
    else:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
```